# Issue in numpy array loop for central difference

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Input array for reference,

```
u = array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

**python function using for loop**

```
import numpy as np
u = np.zeros((5,5))
u[1:-1,1:-1]=1
def cds(n):
    for i in range(1,4):
        for j in range(1,4):
            u[i,j] = u[i,j+1] + u[i,j-1] + u[i+1,j] + u[i-1,j]
    return u
```

above function cds(5) provide the following result by using **for loop**,

```
u=array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   2.,   4.,   5.,   0.],
         [  0.,   4.,  10.,  16.,   0.],
         [  0.,   5.,  16.,  32.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

**same function using numpy**

```
def cds(n):
    u[1:-1,1:-1] =  u[1:-1,2:] +  u[1:-1,:-2] +  u[2:,1:-1] +  u[:-2,1:-1]
    return u
```

But for the same input array(u), function cds(5) using **NUMPY** provide different result.,

```
u=array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  2.,  3.,  2.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  3.,  4.,  3.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  2.,  3.,  2.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

The reason for this problem is, python "for loop" updates every u[i,j] value to the exsisting u array while looping but "numpy" didn't.....

I want same result from numpy as like as from the for loop.

Is there any way to solve this issue in NUMPY? please help me, Thanks in advance...

Comment: You could probably do it with [`np.add.at`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html), though the index arrays and slices involved could get messy.

Comment: This isn't an "issue in numpy". You're trying to implement an iterative algorithm (result of iteration `n` depends on the result of iteration `n-1`) using using numpys `add` operator, which by definition is not iterative. Either find a non-iterative solution to your problem or look into tools designed to implement iterative algorithms.